# how to extract wsdl file from sample soap request and response?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I want to implement a soap web service, where I have given a document that describes the web service alongside sample request and response, I want to create a wsdl which I can use to implement the web service as described in the document and that the client can use to interact with the service, how can I do that ?

Comment: If you add more detail  for what kind of Web Service with documentation, which language for WSDL server and client?, it will increase to get an answer. Your current description is too wide scope.